# Case insensitive search of in memory sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

I have database phonebook and table contacts, Create statement for table contacts looks like this:
    CREATE TABLE 'contacts'(
    'name' text collate nocase,
    'surname' text collate nocase,
    'street_name' text collate nocase,
    'street_number' text collate nocase,
    'city' text collate nocase,
    'post' text collate nocase,
    'post_office_code'text collate nocase,
    'text_to_publish' text collate nocase,
    'area_code' text collate nocase,
    'phone' text collate nocase,
    'fax' text collate nocase,
    'email' text collate nocase)

I managed to load it in memory from java code with:
    "ATTACH 'phonebook' AS tempInMemoryDb" and
    "CREATE TABLE tempInMemoryTable AS SELECT * FROM 'contacts';"

But with Create table .. as select .. resultset is copied to new table without declaring columns properties(in my case collate nocase).

What i need is case insensitive search, but with in memory table, so could you please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the table structure, you can create your table with the same structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tempInMemoryTable(name text collate nocase, ...)
```

and then just copy the records:

```
INSERT INTO tempInMemoryTable SELECT * FROM contacts;
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem, i had the same idea but i thought that it would be slow(i need to copy about 1400000 records in not more than few seconds). Thank you.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` command is just a shorthand for the separate `CREATE`/`INSERT` commands; the amount of work the database has to do is the same.